# Cannot run PHP script in Markdown

Tags: php, markdown

I am trying to run a PHP script to iterate the list of images to be used by the Galleria Javascript plugin. I need to run the script so that Galleria may use it.

Also, I want to run a PHP script to send an email to the specified email address, but the markdown file seems not to allow me to run one.

How can I run a PHP script inside a markdown file or is it impossible to run such script?

Comment: As far as I understand you, the answer is: NO, You can't

Comment: Could you explain in detail why you would want this feature? Wouldn't running JavaScript in markup suffice? (Such as the code snippet seen here on StackOverflow)

Comment: I want to utilize Galleria, and the plugin simply iterates an <img> tag inside its <div> tag. I need to iterate an <img> tag with a list of files inside a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like you're going about it the wrong way.  Markdown is a syntax for readable text.  PHP is a scripting language.  You really aren't supposed to be able to 'run' anything in markdown; a markdown parser will turn markdown into HTML, not PHP, nor will it ever run the result.

If you're iterating in a browser, you'll want to do this entirely in JS.  Do you have a page somewhere that someone could look at to make a suggestion?

Comment: I am working it in my local computer. But the plugin, Galleria, that I am following is here: http://galleria.io/docs/getting_started/beginners_guide/

Comment: So you want to take the resulting HTML of a markdown document, iterate over the images and load them into the plugin?

Comment: yup. exactly what I needed... but how?

Comment: Reading over your other comment, your question is rather different than what you asked.  Also, it's a little crazy.  You want to iterate over a list of system paths in an HTML document and then you want to inject those as img tags into (the/a new) rendered HTML.  Correct so far? The you want to take that HTML and, client-side, use it in a galleria plug-in.  This means that, as inputs, you have system-side markdown, and as output you want client-side web gallery.  Right?  If so, then you just want someone to build a little project for you.    The answer would have to include a zip.

Comment: I believe it's not my objective to ask for someone to do the little project for me. But anyways, I am only testing the flat-file CMS concept, and instead of wasting effort, I've used Joomla over this flat-file CMS. Thank you for answering my question.